# Java api for kml in Play Framework 2.1

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, jak

I'm using Play Framework 2.1 and I want to use the library "Javaapiforkml" (http://labs.micromata.de/display/jak/HelloKML+%28Quickstart%29).

I add dependencies and repository:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "Planificador_VRP"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    "de.micromata.jak" % "JavaAPIforKml" % "2.2.0"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here
    resolvers += "Java.net Maven 2 Repository" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2"
  )

}
```

But I can't import the library. I don't know how to check that it library has downloaded. I hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Good to know some other people use JAK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have to add the repository, Maven repository is already linked.

In your command line just after adding the dependency as you did:

- play clean (just to be sure)
- play compile
- play idea (or play eclipse)

and the library will appear in you "External Librairies"